# Creating a Subsite login

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, javascript, sharepoint-server

Ok, I'm a newbie to Sharepoint, and I don't even know if this is possible. We have a subsite on a Sharepoint server (Office 365). This is what the bosses want:

Front page of the site is this info-gathering Web Part form attached to a list. [image]

Depending on which checkbox they choose, they are to be redirected to one branch of the site or another. Their info is still to be saved in the list.

If the user then leaves his branch of the site, and wants to come back later, they want for them to be taken directly to the branch, without the intermediary step of filling out the form again.

Are these things possible? And if so, please explain how to do this like I'm a 5-year-old. Cause that's about my level of programming experience.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to clarify your situation. SharePoint 2013 server is an on-premises hosting environment while Office 365 is cloud hosted. But at the looks of your description, you are using the on-premises server. You will need to create a custom claims based code to embed with your users. Development using Visual Studio 2012/2013 has a helper class that you can use to make this possible.

Cheers.

Comment: I know we're on Office 365, so maybe we're not on a server. But I don't think I have Visual Studio. I only have Sharepoint Designer. I also don't understand what a "custom claims based code" is.